# Report the accuracy of each epoch with Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to Pytorch. I wrote a script for training my model but I would like to record my accuracy and stuff of each epoch.

Currently, I use 4 lists to record the histories of each epoch and change them to a dataframe and save as CSV. I am wondering what people usually do for this part.

```
def train(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=25):
    train_loss_history = []
    val_loss_history = []
    train_acc_history = []
    val_acc_history = []
   # Training scripts below
```

Answer (score 1):

TensorboardX allows you to plot and store the information you need.